# how to check network maximum avilable speed ubuntu Virtual Machine?

Tags: java, python, ubuntu, network-programming

Is there any programming way to check Maximum available Network and Internet speed using python or JAVA or any other languages in Ubuntu virtual Machine!?

Comment: I don't know why there is so many negative reaction about this question..!

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't. You can check the maximum speed your network interfaces offer but most probably your internet connection is slower than your network interfaces. 
The only way to find out your speed is measure it. A quick google search gave me a site which might offer a web service for what you want: http://speedof.me/api.html